# How to import facebook and google users from expression engine 1.7 to hybridauth?

Tags: feeds, social-network, authentication-authorization

Is there any way to import facebook and google users from expression engine to [hybridauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth)?

I am trying to get users in Drupal 7 environment. Normal users I got from the [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module, but I didn't find anything for Facebook and Google logged in users.